# monaca Onsen UI で setActiveCarouselItemIndex() エラーがでます。

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

monaca+onsen uiで、アプリの勉強をしております。
monaca は、「Onsen UI V2 Angular 1 Minimum」を選択し、新規プロジェクトを作成しました。

参考ページとして
「Onsen UIを使ってスワイプで切り替えられるタブを実装する」
http://cly7796.net/wp/javascript/to-implement-a-tab-to-be-switched-in-the-swipe/
を見つけましたので、そのプログラムをmonacaに入力してテストしました。

スワイプで画面遷移はできたのですが、タブをクリックすると、

```
TypeError: tab.setActiveCarouselItemIndex is not a function
```

というエラーがでます。

該当箇所のhtmlファイルは、

```
<ons-carousel var="tab" swipeable auto-scroll ng-style="tabHeight">
    <ons-carousel-item ng-repeat="belong in belongData.belongs"> 
       (表示内容）
    </ons-carousel-item>
</ons-carousel>
```

となっており、jsファイルは、

```
$scope.changeTab = function(index) {
    tab.setActiveCarouselItemIndex(index);
}
```

となっております。

まだ勉強を始めたばかりで、もしかするとonsen uiのバージョンが関係するのかと思いましたが、よくわかりませんでした。

何かヒントでもいただけると助かります。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v2では一部のAPIが変更されています。
`setActiveCarouselItemIndex()`は[v2.0.0-beta.9](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/1d6d9f287036fa7cb30275bab44f33020a712407/CHANGELOG.md#v200-beta9)で`setActiveIndex()`にリネームされました。

v2のAPIドキュメントの日本語版はまだ用意されていないようですので、さしあたりこちらの英語版を参照してください。
https://onsen.io/v2/docs/js.html